# Fetch API sending post request gets null

Tags: jquery, post, fetch

I am having some dificulty sending data via post using Fetch API, the server (NETCORE 3.1) only receives an null.

JS

```
    async function exportRelatorio(tabela) {
        var data = JSON.stringify(tabela);
        const resp = await fetch("/Relatorios/ExportRelatorio/", {
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            },
        });
        if (!resp.ok) throw new Error("Not OK");
        const blob = await resp.blob();
        // Programatically create a link and click it:
        const a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.download = "circuitos.xlsx";
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        setTimeout(() => {  // Clean up
            URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href);
            a.parentNode.removeChild(a);
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Server

```
  [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult ExportRelatorio([FromBody] string data)
        {
            var relatorios = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Relatorio>>(data);
            

        }
```

I cant seem to find what I am doing wrong.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Instead of `data` shouldn't it be `body` : `body: JSON.stringify(data)`

Comment: It should. Thanks, I Knew it was something so little as that.